# Dockerfile assign bash command to var

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, var, assign

I need to assign bash command to var in Dockerfile. Following is what I guess:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN data=$(ls /)
ENV DATA $data
```

After running container (`docker run exec -it <image> bash`), then `echo $DATA` output is empty. I have searched on google, but noway. I am stuck!

How to assign bash command to value in dockerfile?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, since `RUN` command spawns its own shell.

Alternatively, you can save the information to some file, and use an `ENTRYPOINT` to set the env variable using some script once the container is running.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set any variables while building docker image, because image build as layered filesystem, after executing `RUN` command instruction, it will execute command in run time and exit, so you can write docker file like below:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN echo 'export data=$(ls /)' >> ~/.bashrc
ENV DATA $data
```